# Jquery solution hide/show easing expandable effect?

Tags: jquery, hide, show, expand

Hi does anyone know an effective jquery fix that does something like the sidebar effect on this website. I suppose its like an easing expandable effect?

http://wordpress.digitalnature.ro/mystique/

Thanks judi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [jquery slideDown](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown#speedcallback)

Comment: Would you know if theres anyway to specify which divs it applies the effect too? It currently automates to all divs.

Comment: you can specify an id for the div you want to have slide, and then call it with $("#your_id").slideDown(..)